# How to prevent a method returns a default value before finishing its function?

Tags: android, callback, android-asynctask, android-library

I have 2 projects: App Project and own library.
My project have this code:

**main.java (MyProject)**

```
...
// call method Lib.download()
String nameFiles[] = {"do.mp3","re.mp3","mi.mp3","billiejean.mp3"};
String url = "http://myweb.net/getfiles/";
if( Lib.download(Main.this, url, nameFiles, "internal", "folderExtra" ) == 1){
    System.out.println("finish");
} else {
    System.out.println("error download");
}
```

**The problem is that Lib.download return the default value without waiting for it to finish the rest of code.**
I'm trying controller this with Semaphore / CountDownLatch / whiles but it doesn't work and also i'm trying implement a callback but without success because classes for "download" must be out of my project. Any help?

**The downloads are done correctly but the download method returns the value before completing the downloads ...
My intention is to call a method "download" from any activity, this launch the dialog process and the rest of my activity code does not run until this method "download" returns a value.**

**Lib.java (MyLib)**

```
/** DOWNLOADER WITH PROCESSDIALOG **/
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Context context;
    String urlName; 
    String[] filesToDownload;
    int downloadOK = -1;
    int currentFile = -1;
    int totalFiles = 0;
    String typeStorage = "internal";
    String folder = "";
    CountDownLatch controlLatch;
    public int download(Context ctx, String urlName, String[] filesToDownload, String typeStorage, String extraFolder ){
            this.context = ctx;
            this.urlName = urlName;
            this.filesToDownload = filesToDownload;
            this.totalFiles = filesToDownload.length;
            this.typeStorage = typeStorage;

            /** Almacenamiento de la descarga - Interno o externo **/
            if (typeStorage.equalsIgnoreCase("internal")) {
                System.out.println("internal");
                this.folder = context.getFilesDir().toString() + "/";
            } else if (typeStorage.equalsIgnoreCase("external")) {
            }

            /** EXTRA OPTIONALL **/
            if (extraFolder != null && extraFolder != "") {
                folder += extraFolder;
            }

            File directoryFile = new File(folder);
            if (!directoryFile.isDirectory()) {
                if (!directoryFile.mkdir()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "problems create directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setTitle("Descargando recursos...");

            // controlLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

            startDownload();
            /* 
            try {
                System.out.println("STOP");
                controlLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            */          
        return downloadOK;
    }
private void startDownload() {
    currentFile++;
    System.out.println("startDownload!");
    if (currentFile < totalFiles) {
        pDialog.setMessage("Descargando " + (currentFile + 1) + " de " + totalFiles + "\n\n(..." + filesToDownload[currentFile] + ")");
        System.out.println("startDownload currentFile +[" + currentFile + "] totalFiles [" + totalFiles + "]");
        System.out.println("file: " + filesToDownload[currentFile].toString());
        new DownloaderFile().execute(filesToDownload[currentFile]);
    }
}

private class DownloaderFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            File checkFile = new File(folder + params[0]);
            if(!checkFile.exists()){
                URL urlFinal = new URL(urlName+params[0]);
                URLConnection connection = urlFinal.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlFinal.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(folder + params[0]);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("The file " + filesToDownload[currentFile] + " is downloaded"  );
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
        return "ok";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("-1");
        File checkFile = new File(folder + filesToDownload[currentFile]);
        if(!checkFile.exists()){
            System.out.println("pDialogShow");
            pDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
        System.out.println("10");
        if (currentFile == (totalFiles - 1)) {
            System.out.println("FINISH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            currentFile = 0;
            pDialog.dismiss();
            downloadOK = 1;
            //controlLatch.countDown();

        } else {
            if (res.equals("ok")) {
                startDownload();
            } else {
                System.out.println("error download");
                downloadOK = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks would run at separate thread once your `.execute()` is called. Your calling line `startDownload()` will never wait for AsyncTask to return any value, what you can do is:

1. Implement some callback interface on your main activity, so that your onPostExecute method would be able to notify your main activity once the operation is finished.
2. As you're the one developing this library, consider moving the AsyncTask to your main activity, and leave very plain download functions (what in your doInBackground method) in the library.
3. Use LocalBroadcastManager to send a broadcast from your library, listen and react to it on your main.java